# Missing cursor in ubuntu 1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, resolution, cursor

I am using ubuntu 13.10 and I wanted to install NVidia drivers.
I had few issues so I have chosen the way of X server settings. But again, some problems 'cause the conflict between Niveau and Nvidia drivers. So I decided to say Niveau goodbye and unninstalled it...

Since then it always popped error message that said that theres problem in my computer, but no problem Nvidia drivers worked well. But now it after startup pops another message, long as 2 workspace screens which saiz something like "Can't use saved screen settings" with this log:

žádný z vybraných režimů nebyl kompatibilní s možnými režimy:
Zkouší se režimy CRTC 633
CRTC 633: zkouší se režim 1600×900@60Hz s výstupem na 1360×768@60Hz (průchod 0)

.

.

.

CRTC 634: zkouší se režim 640×480@60Hz s výstupem na 1360×768@60Hz (průchod 1)

I have ubuntu ported to czech language, but it means that it tries mode 1600x900@Hz with output 1360x768@60Hz. and that repeats until 640x480@60Hz

This error message is still fine, if I let it be it makes no problem I can still see my cursor, but after I close it, my screen refreshes and cursor dissappears...

any ideas or mercyfull souls ?

- Zututukulipa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your mouse is not working -

Press Super key for opening Dash

Search the term **System Settings** make enter on it

Go to Display

If there is mention **Unknown Moniter** disable it.

Use Tab key for navigation and enter for selecting.

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: This actually worked

It shown like I had 2 monitors and the main screen was chosen as 2nd monitor... Thanks